# what is difference between set and setCookie method

Tags: c#, asp.net

There is `HttpCookieCollection.set(HttpCookie cookie)` method and `HttpResponseBase.SetCookie(HttpCookie cookie)` method in c#.

I want to know the difference between set and setcookie method. ( I know that they both update cookies).

Answer (score 2):

The **HttpResponse.SetCookie** method is intended for internal use only, you should not call it in your code. Instead, you can call the HttpResponse.Cookies.Set method, as the following example shows.
Updates an existing cookie in the cookie collection.

```
public void SetCookie (System.Web.HttpCookie cookie);
```

But **HttpCookieCollection.Set(HttpCookie)** Method use for Updates the value of an existing cookie in a cookie collection. The Set method first checks to see if a cookie already exists in the collection and if so updates it. The Set method does not allow duplicate cookies in the cookie collection.

```
public void Set (System.Web.HttpCookie cookie);
```

Comment: What example? That's just the function signature. Oh I see: this is mostly copy/pasted from MSDN.